# Are there any already established software packages for BDD

Tags: bdd, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I know it would be possible to do Behavior Driven Development in AX by adding code for every form and then using that to drive the development cycle.

But it seems as if we're starting right at the bottom.

Are there any existing ISV solutions that have tried something like this, so that we wouldn't have to start from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AX has [Unit Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa874515.aspx) build in which could be a small start.

For a full blown BDD tool pack you would have to rely on third part tools.

Check [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Unit_Testing) as well.